# Github Actions Scripts - create comment as raw text

Tags: javascript, markdown, github-actions

As it is currently, when using

```
github.rest.issues.createComment({ issue_number, owner, repo, body: "..." })
```

the `body` portion is interpreted as Markdown in the comment, so e. g. multiple spaces will be rendered as one space and tokens like `<hello>` won't be displayed at all because they are interpreted as HTML tags. I would like to prevent both of these mechanisms by posting a comment as raw text instead of Markdown. Is this possible?

Comment: Tokens like what? I think you have a typo there

Comment: Also, I don't think this has anything todo with actions or script. This is a question of what GitHub accepts as input when creating an issue. I don't think this is possible when creating an issue via UI. Markdown is the only accepted input. Perhaps you should use some form of quoting if you want to render special characters or multiple whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you. Ironically, because questions here are also formatted with Markdown, the `<hello>` I put in the original contents wasn't visible here either - just like in Github :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue-comment), there is no way to disable markdown.

As a workaround you could wrap the body of your comment in triple backquotes, triple tilde or `pre` tags to display it as a fenced code block :

````
```text
```

~~~text
~~~
````

Adding the word "text" should disable the syntax highlighting.

Comment: I've visited that page before and couldn't, and still can't, find the place where it says you can't disable Markdown. Still, thank you for the code block suggestion, that sounds good!